# Operator Console App - Java/Flex

Tags: java, apache-flex, sockets

We are in the middle to evaluate the technology choice to re-design an operator console application. The operator console as a hosted contact center has the abilities to queue the inactive calls, and hold, answer, transfer the active calls.

The legacy operator console used Java Swing. We want to use the latest RIA technology (Flex/Silverlight) to retire the legacy one. But the question is Flex/Silverlight can implement the functions like hold, transfer the calls? Based on my experiences, Flex can listen Java socket to receive XML data? Does it work well to receive voice data? Thanks.

Comment: yes, it needs to request server-side. think the server-side used Java socket, as the legacy front-end based on browser used java swing. not sure, Flex can receive voice data in Java socket.

Answer (score 1):

Flash / Flex does have native access to the computer's microphone with the introduction of the latest player / AIR runtimes.  But, that is probably not what you need.

Yes, Flex supports open sockets and can listn to a server.  To receive voice data, you'll be best served using something on the server side, such as [Flash Media Server](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/) or [Red5](http://osflash.org/red5).

I'm not sure of the technology to integrate such technologies with a traditional phone lines, though.  You may look into [Ribbit APIs](http://developer.ribbit.com/) as one solution.  I was under the impression that Ribbit used Red5 under the hood; and it designed for these type of telephony applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex and Ribbit for that. Ribbit is a company that offers VOIP solutions for web application. I have used in couple of projects and it's really good.

Here is the link to their deve zone (htey support several technologies):
http://developer.ribbit.com/development-center/flash/flash-center

Hope this helps.